# How to write a function that checks if two arrays have the same elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want a typescript function that will take two arbitrary arrays and check if they have the same elements -- regardless of order and regardless of duplicates. How can I do it?

The following function doesn't work:

```
function setEquality(list1:any[], list2:any[]): boolean {
    const difference1 = list1.filter(x => !list2.includes(x));
    const difference2 = list2.filter(x => !list1.includes(x));
    return (difference1.length === 0) && (difference2.length === 0);
}

console.log(setEquality(["A", "B", ["C"]], ["A", "B", ["C"]]))
```

Here is the code in action: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrAM4FM4FECOEBDAGwTgE8AKEtOARgC4CoyBtAXQBphq4AmR5uwCU9YACMkSIhibAA3gChQy4DBQ1gAEwRgwGAE4ZYGWsAC83BDVoA6MAiJwDFAB7mAfMACEPXjYSwRBCaGGiuQkIA3EoqIGpQGtq6BkYwGLzmljR%209o7ObmaePlZ0-oHBoeFRMbGGcBD6qBRJeobGttJQAOZwABbmZhYADELAAGRjwM06ranpNp09-YPD1coAvgo1qupSGAtIXRSYOPjEpJQsAEQAgldcVwBC98DXAMJXbJyvty9PL%209PmwIkA).

The `console.log` line at the end should print true, but it prints false.

Comment: ["C"] is not equal to another ["C"]

Comment: You have to define "same". Do you want a recursive definition where, if the array contains arrays, that these arrays are themselves compared with setEquality, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB87kW)? If so you'll find that this comparison becomes expensive and ill-defined for deep or recursive structures. What about non-array objects? How do you determine if they're the "same"? We need more input/output examples and you need to think of edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
function setEquality(a: any[], b: any[]): boolean {
  // Check if the arrays are the same length
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // Create a set of the elements in array `a`
  const setA = new Set(a.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item)));

  // Check if each element in array `b` is in the set
  for (const element of b) {
    const strElement = JSON.stringify(element);
    if (!setA.has(strElement)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If we've made it this far, the arrays are equal
  return true;
}


console.log(setEquality(["A", "B", ["C"]], ["A", "B", ["C"]])) // true
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It prints `false`, not `true`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes, you're right, I rushed my answer, corrected the version. Now it really returns true. Thank you very much !

Comment: This approach works, but not always. `JSON.stringify()` can't serialize everything.

Comment: You can also just do `first.every(element => second.has(element))`